# postman.setNextRequest not working properly

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

I have a collection which runs from GitLab CI and before deploying it I'll usually try it in pm collection runner.

The collection has different calls with the same structure based on the same code with different datasets. Something like the following example:

```
call 1
call 2 
call 3
call 4
call 1 
call 5
call 6
call 7
call 1
etc...
```

based on "call 1" conditions, the `postman.setNextRequest()` decides whether to run call 2, 3 or 4 and so on.

The code works fine but the last "loop" (meaning something like: call 1, call 8, call 9, call 10) doesn't work and the `postman.setNextRequest()` does nothing.

On Newman/Gitlab CI I get the following string: `Attempting to set next request to $[collection_name]` but the request is not going to be set while on Collection runner I get no errors.

Putting some console logs on the `if` statements where the code goes returns the logs which means it's working properly but seems that **only** for the last conditional loop of requests doesn't work.

the code is the SAME for all the requests.

Here's the code snippet that works for all previous scenarios and not for the last one. The only things I change are "checkJobName()" if string and "postman.setNextRequest" requests

```
const   jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody),
        json_identifier = jsonData.stages;

json_identifier.forEach(function cicla(arr) {
    arr.jobs.forEach(function cicla(job) {

    function checkJobName() {
        if (job.name === "premio_manuale") {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (checkJobName() === true) {
        pm.environment.set("id_job", job.id);
        pm.environment.set("jobName", job.name);
        pm.environment.set("jobStatus", job.status);
        pm.environment.set("jobValidation", job.validation);
        JobStatusPerformer();
    }

    //// check functions 

    function JobStatusPerformer(){
        if (job.status === "success" ) {
                console.log("il job " + job.id + " " + job.label + " è in stato " + job.status + ", vado in idle ");
                postman.setNextRequest("1111");
            } 
            if (job.status === "pending" && job.validation === "manual") {
               console.log("il job " + job.id + " " + job.label + " è in stato " + job.status + " e in modalità " + job.execution + " , avvio il Job Resolve");
               postman.setNextRequest("Resolve_pm");
            }
            if (job.status === "idle" && job.validation === "manual" && job.execution === "manual") {
               console.log("il job " + job.id + " " + job.label + " è in stato " + job.status + " e in modalità " + job.execution + " , avvio il Job Run");
               postman.setNextRequest("Run_pm");
            }
            else if (job.status === "idle" && job.validation === "auto" && job.execution === "auto") {
                console.log("il job " + job.id + " " + job.label + " è in stato " + job.status + " e in modalità " + job.execution + " , attendere l'avvio e risoluzione automatica.");
                postman.setNextRequest("222");
            }
            else if (job.status === "idle" && job.validation === "manual" && job.execution === "auto") {
                console.log("il job " + job.id + " " + job.label + " è in stato " + job.status + " e in modalità " + job.execution + " , il job è in idle, attendere la risoluzione del job precedente. Se già in stato 'success' visualizzare il log errori");
                postman.setNextRequest("333");
            }
            if (job.status === "running" && job.validation === "manual" && job.execution === "manual") {
                console.log("il job " + job.id + " " + job.label + " è in stato " + job.status + " e in modalità " + job.execution + " , avvio il Job resolve");
                postman.setNextRequest("Resolve_pm");
            }
            else if (job.status === "running" && job.validation === "auto" && job.execution === "auto") {
                console.log("il job " + job.id + " " + job.label + " è in stato " + job.status + " e in modalità " + job.execution + " , attendere la risoluzione automatica.");
                postman.setNextRequest("444");
            }
            else if (job.status === "running" && job.validation === "manual" && job.execution === "auto") {
                console.log("il job " + job.id + " " + job.label + " è in stato " + job.status + " e in modalità " + job.execution + " , avvio il Job resolve");
                postman.setNextRequest("Resolve_pm");
            }
            if (job.status === "failed") {
               console.log("lo stato del job " + job.id + " è " + job.status + ". Verificare i log.");
               postman.setNextRequest("555");
            }
            else {
                postman.setNextRequest("666");
            }
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: "The code works fine" - What code? :) Could you share the code that you have in the test script, please? Without that knowledge, this would just turn into a series of guesses. :)

Comment: is your code working properly in postman (runner)?

Comment: @DieGraueEminenz yes it is working properly and i get no errors at all. It is just skipping the request where it should be redirected.

Comment: @DannyDainton I'm working on it to avoid any sensible info exposition, I'll post in a few minutes.

Comment: Code added to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Its still hard to walk through your code without a state-change description of your failing loop. Is this test-code placed in each of the requests? How are they ordered in the collection?

However, you are writing setNextRequest two times e.g. in case job.status==="success"

at first

```js
 if (job.status === "success" ) {
                console.log("il job " + job.id + " " + job.label + " è in stato " + job.status + ", vado in idle ");
                postman.setNextRequest("1111");
            }
```

is executed to set postman.setNextRequest("1111"); and then afterwards in the last line the else satement is executed too.

```js
if (job.status === "failed") {
               console.log("lo stato del job " + job.id + " è " + job.status + ". Verificare i log.");
               postman.setNextRequest("555");
            }
            else {
                postman.setNextRequest("666");
            }
```

And then your original `postman.setNextRequest("1111")` is overwritten by `postman.setNextRequest("666")`
Please keep in mind, setNextRequest doesn't execute the nex Request immediately. It changes only the workflow order.

Please try tou refactor your code, especially JobStatusPerformer() by using else statements.